# stuck on a java setter method

Tags: java, setter

I have a StockList class which contains a linkedlist and can control stock using a variety of method. However i am stuck on what to put inside my method body for my updateItemPrice method.
Do I need to use a setter to set the new item price, if so how would i go about that?

This is my code so far, any help would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
public class StockList {
{
private LinkedList<StockItem> stock
        = new LinkedList<StockItem>();


public StockList() {};


// Adds item to end of stock list
public void addItem(StockItem item) 
{
    this.stock.addLast(item);
}


// Removes item identified by productID from stock list
public void deleteItem(String itemID) 
{
    ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
 {
            StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
    if(item.getitemID() == itemID)
    {
                    stock.remove(itr.previousIndex());
        break;
    }
    }
}


// Updates price of existing item
public void updateItemPrice(String itemID, double price) 
{
    ???
}


// Updates quantity of existing item
public void updateItemQuantity(String itemID, int quantity) 
{…}


// Updates re-order level of existing item
public void updateReOrderLevel(String itemID, 
int reOrderLevel) 
{…}


// Returns formatted representation of the stock list
public String formatStockList()
{…}


// Returns formatted representation of re-order list
// Items are on this list if quantity < reOrderLevel
public String formatReOrderList()
{…}
}




}
```

Comment: I think you should replace `stock.remove(itr.previousIndex());` with `itr.remove();` in `deleteItem()`

Comment: It should be a setter in your `StockItem` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StockItem` need to have the setter method to set Price like  `setPrice`

```
 ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
 {
    StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
    if(item.getitemID() == itemID)
    {
                    item.setPrice(price);
         break;
    }
  }
```

How ever there is also problem in your delete code...

```
public void deleteItem(String itemID) 
{
    ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
 {
            StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
    if(item.getitemID() == itemID)
    {
                    stock.remove(itr.previousIndex());
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

This will give you `concerrent Access exception`. use below code instead.

```
public void deleteItem(String itemID) 
    {
        ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
     {
         StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
        if(item.getitemID() == itemID)
        {
            itr.remove(); // Removes last obejct returned by itr.next()
            break;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: My set method in Stockitem is as follows: public void setprice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

Comment: ok then above should work. and also check for deleteItem. your current implementtion will give you ` concerrent Access exception`

Comment: i'm still getting an error thrown from stock.setPrice(newPrice). it says cannot find symbol. and yes thank you i corrected my deleteitem.

Comment: ok will do. The error i get is: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable newPrice
  location: class StockList

Comment: i originally tried to use price, but got this error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setPrice(double)
  location: variable stock of type LinkedList<StockItem>

Comment: My bad.. updated answer again.. Just typo error. use `item.setPrice(price);` see thats why one should use naming conventions. see updated answer

Comment: now getting the error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setQuantity(int)
  location: variable item of type StockItem. It says as a solution that i should create a setPrice(Double) method in StockItem, but i already have a setter for price?

Comment: dont worry, fixed, i was being blind! Needed to be item.setprice(price); not item.setPrice(price); thanks for all your help

Comment: which java version you are using? if you are using below `1.5` it does not have `autoBoxing`... in that case you need to use `item.setPrice(new Double(price));` or change the `setPrice(Double)` to `setPrice(double)` Hope it helps. Also you can reduce old comments by you on this answer.. to keep it clean :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
 {
            StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
    if(item.getitemID() == itemID)
    {
                    item.setPrice(price);
        break;
    }
    }
```

Nevertheless, it may be a better idea to use an `HashMap<String, StockItem>()` to store the ids of the stock objects and update the price would be more easy for you.

And you should store ids as `Long` instead of `String`, so this would be an `HashMap<Long, StockItem>()`

Comment: +1 This answers the literal question. It might be good to suggest adding a `find(String itemId)` method as that would help with all the needed methods.

Comment: I did look into hashMap, however our assignment has instructed us specifically to use LinkedLists. Thanks for the method body though, will also help me fill in my other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an `itemId`, I would not use a List.  I would use a Map, with `itemId` as the key and the StockItem as the value.  Then your add and delete methods become much simpler

```
Map<String, StockItem> stocks = new HashMap<String, StockItem>();

public void addStockItem(StockItem stockItem) {
    this.stocks.put(stockItem.getItemId(), stockItem);
}

public void deleteStockItem(StockItem stockItem) {
    this.stocks.remove(stockItem.getItemId());
}
```

then updating becomes as simple as getting the appropriate item out of the map and updating its price.

```
public void updateStockItem(String id, Double price) {
     StockItem item = this.stocks.get(id);
     item.setPrice(price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Updates price of existing item
    public void updateItemPrice(String itemID, double price) 
    {
        ListIterator itr = stock.listIterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
 {
            StockItem item = (StockItem)itr.next();
    if(item.getitemID() == itemID)
    {
                    item.setPrice(price);
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everybody's answer here except `@hvgotcodes` has a very basic bug:

```
if(item.getitemID() == itemID) // this won't work!
```

`@hvgotcodes` solution is the correct way of implementing your class. Using a `HashMap` is far better than iterating over `LinkedList` to delete stuff.